# android drawer's item selection from different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a main activity in which I have a drawer and selectItem procedure to process item selection of the drawer:

```
public void selectItem(drawerItems position) {
        if (Utils.userId != 0) {
            switch (position) {
                case userSettings:
                    Fragment frag = new UserSettings();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putSerializable("loginmode", Utils.LoginMode.lmRegistered);
                    frag.setArguments(args);
                    Utils.replaceFragment(frag);
                    break;
                case option2:
                    Utils.replaceFragment(new fragmentX());
                    break;
                case option3:
                    Utils.replaceFragment(new fragmentY());
                    break;
            }
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = position.ordinal();
            if (mCurrentSelectedPosition > 0) {
                mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition - 1, true);//user settings is not part of drawer view
                mDrawerListView.setSelection(mCurrentSelectedPosition - 1);
            } else mDrawerListView.clearChoices();
            setTitle(mDrawerItemTitles[mCurrentSelectedPosition]);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_active_user), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mDrawerListView.clearChoices();
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
```

This is working great as long as I'm working with the drawer, the thing is, I switch fragments also from within a fragment so then I call `Utils.replaceFragment(new fragmentX());` but I'm missing all the other "fun" of selecting an item (title, item focusing etc.).

I wanted to move the selectItem also to the Utils class but I don't have a reference to mDrawerItemTitles, mDrawerListView, mCurrentSelectedPosition etc. I can add them to the Utils class but I was wondering if there is a cleaner, nicer way to achieve what I want.

Another option was to make selectItem public and reach it from the hosted fragment but again, I was wondering if there is a nicer/cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

You could communicate your fragments and your main activity using a callback. Here you have a good explanation with examples.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Thanks. Eventually I realized that I need to call other fragments also from the Utils class (which is not a fragment) so I used the second option I mentioned.